# how to use parameter in xsl?

Tags: xslt

I have a simple xsl file:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="part">
            <div class="part">
            <h2>Part Name:<xsl:value-of select="@partName" /></h2>
            <xsl:for-each select="input">
                <p>
                <input>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@inputName" /></xsl:attribute>
                </input>
                </p>
            </xsl:for-each>

            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

I want to save partname and use it latter. I tried as the following:

```
           <xsl:for-each select="part">
                <div class="part">
                <h2>Part Name:<xsl:value-of select="@partName" /></h2>
**<xsl:param name="part_name"><xsl:value-of select="@partName" /></xsl:param>**
                <xsl:for-each select="input">
                    <p>
                    <input>
                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">**<xsl:value-of select="$part_name" />**-<xsl:value-of select="@inputName" /></xsl:attribute>
                    </input>
                    </p>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

but it doesn't work. I don't know what should do.

Comment: is there an error, or is the value empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably getting the error `Keyword xsl:param may not be used here.`. This is because **xsl:param** should only really be found under the root **xsl:stylesheet** element, and are used for passing values from the external application.

What you need is **xsl:variable** in this case

```
<xsl:variable name="part_name">
  <xsl:value-of select="@partName"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Or simpler still....

```
<xsl:variable name="part_name" select="@partName"/>
```

In fact, you could do away with the variable altogether. Instead of doing this

```
<xsl:value-of select="$part_name"/>
```

You could just do this, to get the value from the parent element

```
<xsl:value-of select="../@part_name"/>
```

Do bear in mind, if you do use a variable, it will only be local to the scope of the **xsl:for-each** in this case.